# How to find the Starting headcount for each month which will be same as Fiscal year starting Headcount

Tags: dax

I am trying to find a attrition % for a fiscal year. So i would need the Starting HC for all the months which should be same as fiscal year starting Headcount.
My fiscal year starts from Aug and ends in July.
Below is the sample data, I have measures for starting and ending Headcount by Month.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAJNR.png)

I am not good in DAX, tried something to, but that did not work.

In calendar table I have created a column to identify Fiscal year start month. And there are relative year number, month number columns also.

This is what i used,
FYStartHC =
CALCULATE( Headcount[StartingHC],'Calendar'[Fiscal Start and End]="Start").

If i use this measure i see only values when the fiscal year start i.e., for only August.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEZ3h.png)

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to start on the first of your fiscal year, you need to use a pattern like this:

CALCULATE(SUM(InternetSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD]),
DATESYTD(DateTime[DateKey], "6-30"))

The "6-30" is for 30 June, the final day of the fiscal year.